# How can I get an specific entry from a website with PHP?

Tags: php, regex

can anybody help me to get an specific entry from a website with PHP?

These Information is on the website: `"price": "10.03"`
I want to extract only the price: 10.03.

I want to use Regex. I am testing my regular expression with an online tool. But is not right: `("price": ")[0-9][.]*`

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
"price": "(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sW7qE4/1)**

You can also use

```
"price": "([^"]+)
```

*PHP Code*

```
$re = "/\"price\": \"(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)/"; 
$str = "\"price\": \"10.03\""; 
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/ZKRE4r)**

Comment: No need for double backslashes in `PHP`: `$re = '~"price": "\d+"~';`.

Comment: thanks!! can you helpe me with another regular expression? i want to get a specific information from this string: "<title>Starmaxx NOVARO ST532 in 205/55 R16 91V | Tekerler</title>". I want only "NOVARO ST532". Can you help me?

Comment: @Jan Code generated from regex101.com...too lazy to change..:)

Comment: @max.schwarz this question is completely unrelated to this one..you can ask this in newer thread..also I am not seeing a specific pattern in this string until the string `NOVARO ST532` is same everywhere..If the input always follows this format, then it can be taken out

Answer (score 1):

The content is formatted in `json`, use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), i.e.:

```
<?php
$json = '{"price": "10.03"}';
$decodeJson = json_decode($json, true);
echo $decodeJson['price'];
//10.03
```

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/eWdh6R)